# query cloudant with python

Tags: python, couchdb, cloudant

There may be an obvious answer to this, but I can't seem to find it anywhere:  what's the best way to query couchdb databases stored on cloudant servers?  I try using temporary views, a la the couchdb.py instructions:

```
>>> db['johndoe'] = dict(type='Person', name='John Doe')
>>> db['maryjane'] = dict(type='Person', name='Mary Jane')
>>> db['gotham'] = dict(type='City', name='Gotham City')
>>> map_fun = '''function(doc) {
...     if (doc.type == 'Person')
...         emit(doc.name, null);
... }'''
>>> for row in db.query(map_fun):
...     print row.key
John Doe
Mary Jane
```

While this works on locally hosted databases, with CloudAnt it returns the error:

```
couchdb.http.ServerError: (403, ('forbidden', 'temp views are disabled on Cloudant'))
```

I've read the cloudant tutorial on querying but the querying syntax proposed seems clumsy and it's not obvious how to work it into python!  Is there an easy way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason Cloudant forbids temp views is because they do not scale. You will need to create a design document with defined views in it. Here is a link to what a design document is like with views defined on it:

http://max.ic.ht/_utils/document.html?action/_design/action

I am not sure about how to do it in couchdb.py, but you might want to try a different python library. Here is a link to the section about creating views in couchquery

http://mikeal.github.com/couchquery/#creating-views

Comment: OK, so I can now create views and am using design documents for this .... the next step is to work out how to send view requests for specific values within couchdb-python's ListField.

Comment: I'd recommend using plain HTTP libraries, like requests.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I am adding a record with python.

```
import requests
import json

doc = {
  'username':'kerrie',
  'high_score':550,
  'level':3
}

auth = ('username', 'password')
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}

post_url = "https://account.cloudant.com/database/kerrie".format(auth[0])

r = requests.put(post_url,  auth=auth,  headers=headers,  data=json.dumps(doc))
print json.dumps(r.json(), indent=1)
```

This is how i query 10 records in Python.

```
import requests
import json
auth = ('username', 'password')
get_url = "https://account.cloudant.com/database/_all_docs?limit=10".format(auth[0])
r = requests.get(get_url, auth=auth)
print json.dumps(r.json(), indent=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just noting that Cloudant now has an official python library, https://github.com/cloudant/python-cloudant.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use [couchdbkit](http://couchdbkit.org/). It makes setting up views easy. I don't think you can use temporary views in Cloudant anymore.

Comment: The server is gone ATM.