# querying Cloudant (couchdb) with python (error 500, unknown query language)

Tags: python, couchdb, cloudant

I am pretty new to Python and Cloudant/couchdb, so please direct me to any resources that you think might be helpful.

I know that there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810064/query-cloudant-with-python) but I will post this in case someone who sees this has a ton of experience with Cloudant (and my error message is different). I am trying to query a bunch of JSON documents stored on cloudant. I have couchpy installed for the purpose of creating views in python. I'm using code from the Mining Social Web O'Reilly Book. The code I'm using works if I'm querying my local couchdb server, but not the cloudant server.

I've been receiving this error message:

```
db.view('index/entity_count_by_doc', group=True)],
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/couchdb/client.py", line 984, in __iter__
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/couchdb/client.py", line 1003, in rows
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/couchdb/client.py", line 990, in _fetch
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/couchdb/client.py", line 880, in _exec
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/couchdb/http.py", line 393, in get_json
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/couchdb/http.py", line 374, in get
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/couchdb/http.py", line 419, in _request
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/couchdb/http.py", line 310, in request
couchdb.http.ServerError: (500, ('unknown_query_language', 'python'))
```

Any ideas on alternative methods of querying using python on cloudant? I'm open to other solutions. I'm sure I'm overlooking something obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very likely receiving the error because `couchpy` is not installed/available at Cloudant in the multi-tenant installation.

[Views](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/views.html) need to be created in JavaScript or Erlang (or you need to sign up for their dedicated install where they may allow Python--contact them).

Cloudant suggests using [CouchDBKit](http://couchdbkit.org/) or [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) (per their [FAQ](https://cloudant.com/for-developers/faq/development/)).

Comment: Thanks - eventually figured out the couchpy issue, but had missed the couchdbkit tip. Much appreciated.

Comment: Cloudant only supports Javascript views at this point (aside from the built-in _sum, _count and _stats reducers).